# Cobol, Code 65 File Locked

Tags: cobol

I am trying to access the same file to do two certain tasks. The first task is to update, add, and delete records. Access has to be random. The second task is to display all records on console. Access has to be sequential. I receive `code 65 File locked` from COBOL because the program is trying to access the same file twice the same time. Is there any way to fix this error? Or is there an different way to do this? Or do I have to write a separate program to display the record on console? I am stuck!

```
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
       SELECT MAST-FILE ASSIGN TO 'G:\CPSC315-COBOL\COBOLAssignments\P15-5\SALES.IND.TXT'
           ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
           ACCESS IS RANDOM
           RECORD KEY M-SALESPERSON-NUM.

       SELECT MAST2-FILE ASSIGN TO 'G:\CPSC315-COBOL\COBOLAssignments\P15-5\SALES.IND.TXT'
           ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
           ACCESS IS SEQUENTIAL
           RECORD KEY M2-SALESPERSON-NUM.

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD MAST-FILE
       LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD.
   01 MAST-RECORD.
       05 M-SALESPERSON-NUM  PIC XXX.
       05 M-CUSTOMER-NAME    PIC X(15).
       05 M-TOTAL-SALES      PIC 9(5)V99.
       05 M-COST-OF-SALES    PIC 9(4)V99.

   FD MAST2-FILE
       LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD.
   01 MAST2-RECORD.
       05 M2-SALESPERSON-NUM     PIC X(3).
       05 M2-SALESPERSON-NAME    PIC X(15).
       05 M2-TOTAL-SALES         PIC 9(5)V99.
       05 M2-COST-OF-SALES       PIC 9(4)V99.

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 SALES-DATA.
       05 SALESPERSON-NUM     PIC X(3).
       05 SALESPERSON-NAME    PIC X(15).
       05 TOTAL-SALES         PIC 9(5)V99.
       05 COST-OF-SALES       PIC 9(4)V99.

   01 OUTPUT-RECORD.
       05                      PIC X(1) VALUE SPACES.
       05 O-SALESPERSON-NUM    PIC X(3).
       05                      PIC X(3) VALUE SPACES.
       05 O-SALESPERSON-NAME   PIC X(3).
       05                      PIC X(3) VALUE SPACES.
       05 O-TOTAL-SALES        PIC 9(5)V99.
       05                      PIC X(3) VALUE SPACES.
       05 O-COST-OF-SALES      PIC 9(4)V99.

   01 PROGRAM-DATA-ITEMS.
       05 I-SALESPERSON-NUM       PIC XXX.
       05 WAIT-OK                 PIC X.
       05 CHOICE                  PIC 9 VALUE 0.
       05 READ-OK                 PIC X.
       05 REWRITE-OK              PIC X.
       05 DELETE-OK               PIC X.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   10-MAINLINE.
       OPEN I-O MAST-FILE
       OPEN INPUT MAST2-FILE
       PERFORM 20-PROCESS-LOOP
       CLOSE MAST-FILE
           MAST2-FILE
       STOP RUN.

   20-PROCESS-LOOP.
       PERFORM UNTIL CHOICE = 5
           PERFORM 30-DISPLAY-MENU
           EVALUATE CHOICE
               WHEN 1  
                   PERFORM 40-UPD-SALES
               WHEN 2
                   PERFORM 90-ADD-SALES
               WHEN 3
                   PERFORM 110-DELETE-SALES
               WHEN 4
                   PERFORM 120-DISPLAY-SALES
            END-EVALUATE
        END-PERFORM.

   30-DISPLAY-MENU.
       DISPLAY 'SALES MAINTENANCE SYSTEM'
       DISPLAY ' '
       DISPLAY ' SELECT ONE:'
       DISPLAY ' '
       DISPLAY '   1. UPDATE SALES RECORD'
       DISPLAY '   2. ADD SALES RECORD'
       DISPLAY '   3. DELETE SALES RECORD'
       DISPLAY '   4. DISPLAY SALES RECORD'
       DISPLAY '   5. QUIT'
       DISPLAY ' '
       DISPLAY 'ENTER CHOICE (1 - 5): ' WITH NO ADVANCING
       ACCEPT CHOICE
       PERFORM UNTIL CHOICE >= 1 AND <= 5
           DISPLAY ' '
           DISPLAY 'ERROR: ENTER CHOICE (1 - 5): ' WITH NO ADVANCING
           ACCEPT CHOICE
       END-PERFORM.

   40-UPD-SALES.
       DISPLAY 'UPDATE SALES: ENTER SALESPERSON NUMBER: ' WITH NO ADVANCING
       ACCEPT SALESPERSON-NUM
       MOVE SALESPERSON-NUM TO M-SALESPERSON-NUM
       PERFORM 50-READ-RECORD
       IF READ-OK = 'N'
           DISPLAY 'RECORD DOES NOT EXIST - PRESS ENTER'
           ACCEPT WAIT-OK
       ELSE
           DISPLAY SALES-DATA
           PERFORM 100-INPUT-NEW-RECORD
           PERFORM 60-REWRITE-RECORD
       END-IF.

   50-READ-RECORD.
       MOVE 'Y' TO READ-OK
       READ MAST-FILE INTO SALES-DATA
           INVALID KEY
               MOVE 'N' TO READ-OK
       END-READ.

   60-REWRITE-RECORD.
       REWRITE MAST-RECORD FROM SALES-DATA
           INVALID KEY
               DISPLAY 'REWRITE ERROR: SALESPERSON NUMBER ' SALESPERSON-NUM
               DISPLAY 'PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE'
               ACCEPT WAIT-OK
       END-REWRITE.

   70-WRITE-RECORD.
       MOVE 'Y' TO REWRITE-OK
       WRITE MAST-RECORD FROM SALES-DATA
           INVALID KEY
               MOVE 'N' TO REWRITE-OK
       END-WRITE
       IF REWRITE-OK = 'N'
           DISPLAY 'WRITE ERROR: SALESPERSON NUMBER ' SALESPERSON-NUM
           DISPLAY 'PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE'
           ACCEPT WAIT-OK
       END-IF.

   80-DELETE-RECORD.
       MOVE 'Y' TO DELETE-OK
       DELETE MAST-FILE
           INVALID KEY 
               MOVE 'N' TO DELETE-OK
       END-DELETE
       IF REWRITE-OK = 'N'
           DISPLAY 'WRITE ERROR: SALESPERSON NUMBER ' SALESPERSON-NUM
           DISPLAY 'PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE'
           ACCEPT WAIT-OK
       END-IF.

   90-ADD-SALES.
       DISPLAY 'ADD SALES RECORD: ENTER SALESPERSON NUMBER: ' WITH NO ADVANCING
       ACCEPT SALESPERSON-NUM
       MOVE SALESPERSON-NUM TO M-SALESPERSON-NUM
       PERFORM 50-READ-RECORD
       IF READ-OK = 'Y'
           DISPLAY 'RECORD ALREADY EXISTS - PRESS ENTER'
           ACCEPT WAIT-OK
       ELSE
           PERFORM 100-INPUT-NEW-RECORD
           PERFORM 70-WRITE-RECORD
           IF REWRITE-OK = 'Y'
               DISPLAY 'RECORD ' SALESPERSON-NUM ' ADDED TO FILE'
               DISPLAY 'PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE'
               ACCEPT WAIT-OK
           END-IF
       END-IF.

   100-INPUT-NEW-RECORD.
       MOVE SALESPERSON-NUM TO M-SALESPERSON-NUM
       DISPLAY '       ENTER SALESPERSON NAME: ' WITH NO ADVANCING
       ACCEPT SALESPERSON-NAME
       DISPLAY '           ENTER TOTAL SALES: ' WITH NO ADVANCING
       ACCEPT TOTAL-SALES
       DISPLAY '               ENTER COST OF SALES: ' WITH NO ADVANCING
       ACCEPT COST-OF-SALES.

   110-DELETE-SALES.
       DISPLAY 'DELETE SALES RECORD: ENTER SALESPERSON NUMBER: ' WITH NO ADVANCING
       ACCEPT SALESPERSON-NUM
       MOVE SALESPERSON-NUM TO M-SALESPERSON-NUM
       PERFORM 50-READ-RECORD
       IF READ-OK = 'N'
           DISPLAY 'RECORD DOES NOT EXIST - PRESS ENTER'
           ACCEPT WAIT-OK
       ELSE
           PERFORM 80-DELETE-RECORD
           IF DELETE-OK = 'Y'
               DISPLAY 'RECORD DELETED - PRESS ENTER'
               ACCEPT WAIT-OK
           END-IF
       END-IF.

   120-DISPLAY-SALES.
       MOVE SALESPERSON-NUM TO M2-SALESPERSON-NUM
       MOVE SALESPERSON-NAME TO M2-SALESPERSON-NAME
       MOVE TOTAL-SALES TO M2-TOTAL-SALES
       MOVE COST-OF-SALES TO M2-COST-OF-SALES
       READ MAST2-FILE
           AT END MOVE HIGH-VALUES TO M2-SALESPERSON-NUM
       END-READ
       PERFORM UNTIL M2-SALESPERSON-NUM = HIGH-VALUES
           MOVE M2-SALESPERSON-NUM TO O-SALESPERSON-NUM
           MOVE M2-SALESPERSON-NAME TO O-SALESPERSON-NAME
           MOVE M2-TOTAL-SALES TO O-TOTAL-SALES
           MOVE M2-COST-OF-SALES TO O-COST-OF-SALES
           DISPLAY OUTPUT-RECORD
           READ MAST2-FILE
               AT END MOVE HIGH-VALUES TO M2-SALESPERSON-NUM
           END-READ
       END-PERFORM.

   end program Program1.
```

Comment: do them as two separate passes and close and open the file as required between the passes?

Comment: Yes sir! The Mast-file is random access so open i-o and close, mast2-file is sequential so open input to read and then close. Same file for 2 passes ==> code 65 error

Comment: Please update your 10-MAINLINE paragraph with the code you have for the 'two pass' version of the code. it should be something like: OPEN I-O MAST-FILE.  PERFORM 20-RANDOM-PROCESS-LOOP, CLOSE MAST-FILE. OPEN INPUT MAST2-FILE. PERFORM 21-SEQUENTIAL-PROCESS-LOOP. CLOSE MAST2-FILE.

Comment: Ryan! It's still causing code 65 file locked. I think because I access the same file at the same time. Is there any way to unlock the file?

Comment: It would be nice to know how you got on with your other question.

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file I-O, that means you open it for Input and Output. Get rid of your second file.

To position your file for displaying the data, you can READ with a KEY and then READ ... NEXT ..., or you can use START ... and then READ ... NEXT.

Always use the FILE STATUS in the ASSIGN. Then use the file-status field you tell COBOL to put the file status in to, to check the previous IO. Use it for end-of-file (value of "10"). Use 88s. You don't then need the INVALID KEY and AT END  and all the END- statements associated with IO can go, because you then don't have a built-in condition with the IO. Which will simplify things.

Your structure is very good for a beginner. Refreshing to see no PERFORM ... THRU ....

I'd suggest you try the effect of a single full-stop/period in column 12 on a line of its own. You'll then be able to move the last line of code from a paragraph without having to think about the full-stop/period attached to it (because it isn't attached to it).

Use more PERFORMs. OPEN and CLOSE are not vital to the logic of the program. Hide them away in paragraphs, do the FILE STATUS checking on them. Same with the READ/WRITE/DELETE and any other IO statements you end up with. Hide them in well-named procedures which you PERFORM.

Consider the size (number of lines) of some of your IFs. Put the code in a well-named procedure, and the code can be "read" at a high level by a human, with the detail only being looked at if needed.

Do not, do not, do not, mess around with two files. Do not, do not, do not OPEN the same file twice (I've written a few COBOL programs in my time, and I've never, ever, considered that a reasonable way to achieve anything, let alone the simple task you have).

You may want to consider DYNAMIC instead of RANDOM (this is what it is for). You use RANDOM if you are *only* doing random access. You actually want to do sequential access as well (look for references to skip-sequential access for further discussion).

```
SELECT MAST-FILE ASSIGN TO 'G:\CPSC315-COBOL\COBOLAssignments\P15-5\SALES.IND.TXT'
       ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
       ACCESS IS RANDOMREWRITE-OK = 'N'
       RECORD KEY M-SALESPERSON-NUM
       FILE STATUS IS W-MAST-FILE-STATUS.
```

...

```
01  W-MAST-FILE-STATUS                    PIC XX.
    88  W-MAST-FILE-LAST-IO-OK            VALUE "00".
    88  W-MAST-FILE-EOF                   VALUE "10".
    88  W-MAST-FILE-REC-NOT-FOUND         VALUE "23".
    88  W-MAST-FILE-OR-OR-NOT-FOUND       VALUE "00" "23".
```

...

```
50-READ-RECORD.
    MOVE 'Y' TO READ-OK
    READ MAST-FILE INTO SALES-DATA
        INVALID KEY
            MOVE 'N' TO READ-OK
    END-READ.
```

Becomes:

```
50-READ-RECORD.
    READ MAST-FILE KEY key-name INTO SALES-DATA
    IF NOT ( W-MAST-FILE-OR-OR-NOT-FOUND ) 
        some code to deal with the pickle, which is nothing to do with 
        business-logic, so hide it away
    END-IF
    .

80-DELETE-RECORD.
    MOVE 'Y' TO DELETE-OK
    DELETE MAST-FILE
        INVALID KEY 
            MOVE 'N' TO DELETE-OK
    END-DELETE
    IF REWRITE-OK = 'N'
        DISPLAY 'WRITE ERROR: SALESPERSON NUMBER ' SALESPERSON-NUM
        DISPLAY 'PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE'
        ACCEPT WAIT-OK
    END-IF.
```

Becomes:

```
80-DELETE-RECORD.
    DELETE MAST-FILE
    IF NOT W-MAST-FILE-LAST-IO-OK
        DISPLAY 'WRITE ERROR: SALESPERSON NUMBER ' SALESPERSON-NUM
        DISPLAY 'PRESS ENTER TO CONTINUE'
        ACCEPT WAIT-OK
    END-IF
    .
```

Each IO paragraph becomes self-contained, self-verifying, and the FILE STATUS field naturally bears only good conditions when you are in your business logic. The "can't happen" (but will, one day) you deal with in these paragraphs.

You code elsewhere simplifies. Your number of "flags" is reduced (the value of the FILE STATUS field replaces the need for the flags) your IOs have no conditional part, so don't need the END- scope delimiter.

A tip about numbering paragraphs. Don't do it until you have tested sufficiently that you are happy with the structure of the logic. Once you are happy with that, rearrange the paragraphs so that the paragraph is always physically *after* the PERFORM of it. Then put the numbers on. The physical layout of your code then represents the structure of your program logic.

If you number first, you'll end up with the situation you have - you have numbers, but they infer nothing. It is much more tedious to "renumber" paragraphs than it is to add paragraph numbers where there were none (use the power of the editor/utilities available to you to do this numbering).

Comment: Would it be useful to provide code examples based on the supplied code as a 'good example' of what you mean? i.e. show the 'real' code' that you want them to use? You mention that they have a 'reasonable' program structure. How should it really look? Publish good code examples? That is the best way to learn; by looking at good code.

Comment: @RyanVincent I've done some. Simplify, reorder. That's all it needs, plus to use the same file for the I-only which I-O as no problem with, which is just a case of getting rid of the second file in favour of using the first. Modern proverb: Provide education to University level for the man, so he decides whether to spend his life fishing, or perhaps doing something which allows him to buy fish, meat, computers, designer-clothes, somewhere to live, stocks & shares and foreign holidays, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response Bill, it makes a lot of sense.